# Why is Autopilot Kubernetes Cluster is so expensive compared to standard cluster on GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I run software of a website on Google Kubernetes Engine. I wanted to try autopilot clusters rather than standart clusters. After days of trial, I saw that it is so expensive. Before autopilot clusters, I used standart clusters with 2 nodes (2 cpu, 4GB ram for each node, medium one). Here is the chart from billing. Right hand side is the cost of autopilot, the top blue area is autopilot cpu cost.

Do you have any explanation? It seems that autopilot clusters are expensive, do you think it justifies the cost with its features?

[image]

Comment: "the top blue area is autopilot cpu cost" I was wondering what the other colors represent ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a pod in kubernetes autopilot you have to specify the resources that the pod will consume (by default are 0.5 cpu, 1GiB of ephemeral storage and 2 GiB of RAM). Check the resources that you are requesting and adjust them to your needs (you can use an autoscaler or manage them manually).

Also keep in mind that autopilot is more expensive than default GKE (and the minimum resources requested by a pod are higher too)

[Autopilot resource ranges](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#allowable_resource_ranges)

Answer (score 0):

While GKE Autopilot option seems more expensive on paper when you compare its vCPU and memory cost with other GCP machines, compared to GKE Standard, it allows for better resource allocation.

GKE Standard charges by GCP nodes, meaning you have to purchase resources in blocks based on the machine type used by your nodes. This leads to you getting charged for unutilised resources.

Kubernetes also recommends having additional resources in idle to handle pod fail-overs, allowing  pods to be moved between nodes. With GKE Standard, you are responsible for managing and paying for these idle resources while GKE Autopilot handles all of these in the background and you are only charged only for resources used.

Unless you plan your resources carefully and the demand does not change much over time, GKE Autopoilt is a more cost-effective option.

For a more detailed discussion on this topic, including charts and a price comparison, I recommend checking out this Medium post: [GKE Autopilot Cost Efficiency](https://medium.com/@gallaghersam95/gke-autopilot-cost-efficiency-c7d5b01946dd).